# Quality of life Vs. Life Quality

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expression-choice, academia

In the context of the following excerpt, what expression should I use? And why?

> *The husband's role is a fundamental element for the sick wife's well-being and **life quality/quality of life**.*

Note that I gave the phrase a slight nominal twist for copyright concerns, and it should be used in an Academic context.

Comment: "Quality of life" is an idiom with a well-established meaning (and one that is appropriate for the above example).  "Life quality" would probably be understood, but might cause some confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [**quality of life**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quality%20of%20life)

> How good or bad a person's life is

Generally, it's the stock term for the happiness and healthiness of an individual. Do note that it is "life" and not "live".